# how to tune the "DataNode maximum Java heap size" in hadoop clusters

Tags: java, hadoop, ambari, datanode

I searched in google to find info about how to tune the value for - **DataNode maximum Java heap size** ,except this one -

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/74076/datanode-high-heap-size-alert.html

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html

but not found formula to calculate the value for **DataNode maximum Java heap size**

the default value for **DataNode maximum Java heap size** , is 1G

and we increase this value to 5G , because in some case we saw from datanode logs error about heap size

but this isn't the right way to tune the value

so any suggestion or good article how to set the right value for - datanode logs error about heap size ?

lets say we have the following hadoop cluster size:

1. 10 datanode machines , with 5 disks , while each disk has 1T
2. Each data node have 32 CPU
3. Each data node have 256G memory

Based on this info can we find the formula that show the right value for - "**datanode logs error about heap size**" ?

**regarding to hortonworks:**
they advice to set the Datanode java heap to 4G
but I am not sure if this case can covered all scenario?

ROOT CAUSE: DN operations are IO expensive do not require 16GB of the heap.

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/74076/datanode-high-heap-size-alert.html

```
RESOLUTION: Tuning GC parameters resolved the issue -
4GB Heap recommendation : 
-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:NewSize=800m 
-XX:MaxNewSize=800m -XX:+UseParNewGC 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `hadoop-env.sh` (also some field in Ambari, just try searching for heap), there's an option for setting the value. Might be called `HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS` in the shell file

8GB is generally a good value for most servers. You have enough memory, though, so I would start there, and actively monitor the usage via JMX metrics in Grafana, for example.

The namenode might need adjusted as well https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/43838/scaling-the-hdfs-namenode-part-1.html

Comment: , see my update in the question , hortonwork suggest to limit the size to 4G and reconfigure the other values as -XX:NewSize=800m  , and -XX:MaxNewSize=800m -XX:+UseParNewGC  , etc , so seems that they not satisfy the high value of the datanode java heap size , what is your opinion ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the datanode really needs heap for because they are just holding data on disk, not in memory or processing it actively

Comment: I would maybe try G1GC if you are running into memory issues , but a true resolution would require a heap dump analysis over time

Comment: yes you right and because that , I not understand why you happy with 8G , I think this is high value

Comment: so do you think that it will be good to take the configuration from hortonworks ?

Comment: HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:NewSize=800m -XX:MaxNewSize=800m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8"

Comment: It's there platform, and they deal with these issues all the time, so I'm not sure why you're not trusting them. I don't think you need 8, I'm just saying you have enough memory to support it. However, monitoring the heap usage will tell you if you won't need all of it

Comment: do you have advice how to - monitoring the heap usage ? ( its CLI or API or else ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184829/discussion-between-judy-and-cricket-007).

Comment: Like I said, Grafana is a good option. For example - https://risdenk.github.io/2018/03/12/improving-hortonworks-hdp-monitoring.html

Answer (score -1):

the recommendation is to keep it 1GB per million data blocks.

Comment: This is for namenode, not datanode